# Mockito+Kotlin+SpringBoot, `when` section doesn't mock, but invoke method meant to be mocked

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, testing, mockito

I'm trying to modify existing test of kotlin+springboot project.

```
Mockito.`when`(serviceA.getData(anyString())).thenReturn(data)// existing mocking
Mockito.`when`(serviceB.getUserId()).thenReturn(userUuid.toString())// my mocking
```

both serviceA and serviceB are mocks, created in same way,
but behave differebtly. I placed break points in ServiceA.getData and ServiceB.getUserId methods. So when i run test in debug mode Mockito.`when` for ServiceA.getData expectedly doesn't invoke ServiceA.getData method, while Mockito.`when`(serviceB.getUserId()) unexpectedly calls ServiceB.getUserId - i see it in invokations stack and code stops at break point in this method.

Never met this in java, so what am i doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: hmm hard to see.  Could you show how you created the Mocks? As well, if there are other Tests that use ServiceB, and are also @SpringbootTests.   The reason I ask is because the tests contexts is usually cached between SpringBootTests, so perhaps some other test is enforcing (CallRealMethod)

Comment: I really don't know how is it possible but the point is in signature of serviceB.getUserId, actually there is argument initialization like serviceB.getUserId(userId: String = getUserId()) when removed part '= getUserId()', method call was mocked as expected.